# Limit ConnectionTimeout for Oracle Database

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, database-connection, connection-timeout

How can I limit timeout for connecting to Oracle Database? I use devart dotConnect Express Edition on data access layer. I tried add `Connection timeout=30;` to connection string but it doesn't give right result (even a little weird, first time it really limits to 30 seconds, but not on all connection attempts). Then I find out that

> Connection Timeout    Time (in seconds) to wait while trying to establish
>   a connection before terminating the attempt and generating an error. A
>   value of 0 indicates no limit. The default value is 15 seconds.
>   Available in Direct mode only.

[from Devart site](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection~ConnectionString.html)

I can't use direct mode because I use Express Edition. Then I tried to set this parameters in `TNSNAMES.ORA`

```
DB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (CONNECT_TIMEOUT=11)
    (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10)
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.100.8)(PORT = 1521)
       )
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE_NAME = DB1)
    )
  )
```

Still works incorrect. OK, going down and try yo set connection timeout in `SQLNET.ORA`

```
SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 5
```

Another one fail! Does anyone know how can I set timeout restricting allowing time to connect to DB1? It now finishes connection (connection fails) for approximately 20 seconds.

Comment: This might help http://dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?showtopic=11745

Comment: I think its also recommended by [**Oracle**](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/sqlnet.htm) that you also add `INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_*listener_name*` (with value lower than `INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Devart's dotConnect library, but looking at the [`OracleConnection`](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection_members.html) class it seems that you should be able to close the connection after a certain period of time by calling [`OracleConnection.Close()`](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection~Close.html). This should take you out of the blocking state while you're trying to `Open` the connection.

This is not exactly like setting the timeout, but it may work. Furthermore, check the [`ConnectionTimeout`](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection~ConnectionTimeout.html) property when you're debugging this code in order to confirm that the timeout is properly set.

Answer (score 0):

[`OracleConnection.ConnectionTimeout`](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection~ConnectionTimeout.html) works in Direct mode only. It is ignored when connection is established via Oracle client, which manages connection in this case.