# Parallel Foreach Timeout gracefully close every worker thread

Tags: c#, .net, database, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the following construction:

```
            Parallel.ForEach(Program.config.Root.Elements("databases"), el =>
            {
                try
                {                   
                DBConnection.OpenConnection(el.Attribute("database_alias").Value);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    WriteLog(10, exc);
                }
            });
```

This construction used for initial opening database connections. But by reason of 3rd party component iterations may hangs on whole application. So we improve contruction and get a new one:

```
            Parallel.ForEach(Program.config.Root.Elements("databases"), el =>
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(DBConnection.OpenConnection));
                    t.Start(el.Attribute("database_alias").Value);

                    // Handling 50 seconds timeout
                    if (!t.Join(50000))
                    {
                        t.Abort();
                        // Force closing because connection is hanging with "connecting" state
                        Program.myConnections[el.Attribute("database_alias").Value].Conn.Close();                                                     
                    }                        
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    WriteLog(10, exc);
                }
            });
```

But even now we have alive threads in time. I can see them counting amount in task manager. Does anybody knows how to manage with it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `Thread.Abort()` is usually not a good idea. Can't you cancel the connection in some other way? Also, do you see any active threads in Visual Studio debugger that shouldn't be there?

Comment: @svick I think not. It's just hanging on [Connection.Open()](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection.html) method and that is it.

Comment: What is the value of `ConnectionTimeout`? Can't you set that instead of using `Thread.Abort()`?

Comment: @svick I tried all native ways to limit time for opening connections but with no success. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077885/limit-connectiontimeout-for-oracle-database

Comment: If you just leave the failed connection threads, do they time out eventually?

Comment: @NicholasButler No. They are just accumulating in core application process.

Answer (score 0):

If `Thread.Abort` isn't working, then the threads are probably hung in native code. Actually, aborting a thread is normally a *very bad idea* anyway. Unless you're unloading an AppDomain.

So that's what I would try next: start the threads in a temporary AppDomain and unload it after your 50 sec test.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to move them to a temporary process.

Comment: Could you please give me some sample on that?

Comment: The example on MSDN: [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) covers the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is somewhat difficult to understand, so please see if you can refactor it:

```
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(DBConnection.OpenConnection));
t.Start(el.Attribute("database_alias").Value);

// Handling 50 seconds timeout
if (!t.Join(50000))
{
    t.Abort();
    // Force closing because connection is hanging with "connecting" state
    Program.myConnections[el.Attribute("database_alias").Value].Conn.Close();                                                     
}
```

Try seeing if you can do this instead:

```
Thread t = new Thread(()=>
{
    try
    {
        // I'm not sure what the correct call is for OpenConnection, but the code below
        // seems appropriate. If it's not right, then do it the right way
        DBConnection.OpenConnection(el.Attribute("database_alias").Value);
    }
    catch(ThreadInterruptedException tie)
    {
        // Eat the exception or do something else (i.e. cleanup or whatever)
    }
});
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();

// Handling 50 seconds timeout
if (!t.Join(50000))
{
    // Interrupt the exception instead of aborting it (this should get you out of blocking states)
    t.Interrupt();

    // Force closing because connection is hanging with "connecting" state
    Program.myConnections[el.Attribute("database_alias").Value].Conn.Close();                                                     
}
```